# Assignment operation that does nothing if variable is null?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, variable-assignment

I want to conditionally assign a value to a variable if that variable is already `null`. Furthermore, if that variable is not already `null` I want **nothing** to occur and I want to be able to do all with a single operator.

```
object a = null;
object b = new Something();

// this is essentially what I want but done with an operator:
if(a == null)
{
    a = b;
}

// this is all I feel I have to work with,
a = a || b;
a = a ?? b;
a = a == null ? b : a;

// the above methods all end up performing a = a if a is not null
```

Comment: So I assume `a = a ?? b;` is out?

Comment: @JoelRondeau Appears so - OP doesn't want `a` being assigned back to itself.

Comment: `if(a== null) a = b;`  If you  don't want `a` being assigned back to `a` you're probably going to have to use an `if` statement.

Comment: Can you define a "statement" - is `if () { .. } else { .. }` a single statement or multiple?

Comment: @JoelRondeau. Yessir. I'm trying to avoid the code performing `a = a`.

Comment: Then you have to use the `if` to avoid the assignment. I don't see any other option. Anyway, doing `a = a` shouldn't be a problem at all, unless the setter has some huge logic.

Comment: You says things like `a = a ?? b` end up performing a = a if a is not null, but you don't explain why this is a problem.

Comment: Do you have a reason for not wanting `a = a`?  Is that somehow detrimental to your application?

Comment: `if(a == null) a = b;` already is exactly one statement.  it's *not* multiple statements.  You might want it to be a shorter statement, but it's certainly not multiple statements.

Comment: @Servy I was looking more an **operator** that could perform this. It looks like one doesn't exist.

Comment: @LCIII Well sure; why would you need to create an operator as shorthand for such a simple single statement.  That's not adding a lot of value to the language.

Comment: you can't do `a || b` with objects.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Updated

Since C# 8 this is possible with the [Null-coalescing assignment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#null-coalescing-assignment) operator

```cs
a ??= b;
```

This will only assign `b` to `a` if `a` is `null`

### Original Answer

Although the syntax is verbose

```cs
(a is null?()=>a=b:(Action)(()=>{}))();
```

Let's break it apart

```cs
(                           // Expression starts here
    a is null               // If a == null...
        ? () => a = b       // return lambda that assigns a = b
        : (Action) (        // Else return next lambda casted as Action
            () => {}        // Empty lambda that does nothing
        )                   // End cast
)                           // Expression ends here
();                         // Execute it!
```

Anyway I would just use the one liner if `if(a is null) { a = b; }`

Comment: Why the downvote? this does exactly what the OP asked

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this is just an obscure way to do an `if`. In fact the `?` does that.

Comment: The difference is that ? returns an expression that has to be assigned to some variable. the only way to get rid of that variable  is to make it return lambdas and execute it like javascript self executing functions

Comment: I didn't downvote, it's an interesting hack but I think the code ends up being somewhat cryptic.

Comment: I definitely will just do an if, but I had to post the answer for completeness

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz: As an idea to improve your post, you could add the disclaimer and explain what it does.

Answer (score 8):

if you're concerned about doing this all in a single statement, you're out of luck - C# doesn't have this functionality at the linguistic level and doesn't support operator declaration (as does F#) or overloading of the assignment operator (as does C++). There are, however, a couple of options, if none quite as elegant as you requested.

The `if` statement, as you mentioned, though it can be written as a single line

```
if(a == null) a = b;
```

A helper method which uses a `ref` parameter

```
public void AssignIfNull<T>(ref T target, T value)
{
    if(target == null) target = value;
}

// ...

AssignIfNull(ref a, b);
```

Note the above will *not* work with a Property, since they cannot be passed as a `ref` parameter.

*EDIT*: While the above is similar to [`Interlocked.CompareExchange`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb297966(v=vs.110).aspx), such an alternative returns the *original* value of the first parameter, so it may prove more of a gotcha than implementing the above method.

Or you could carefully rewrite your initial statement to use a null-coalescing (`??`) operator in the initial assignment.

Answer (score 3):

As you said, an `if` statement is what you need. There is no conditional operator that doesn't assign when `null`. An `if` is most suitable in this case (not everything has to be a oneliner).

The best options:

```
if(a == null)
{
    a = b;
}
```

Or:

```
a = a ?? b;
```

In fact, I believe that the latter is optimized away as a simple `if` statement.

Assigning `a` to itself isn't bad. With object references, it is just an assignment of the memory address. For value types, this is just a little chunk of data.

If `a` is actually a property setter, check inside the setter the value has changes:

```
private string a;

public string A
{
    get
    {
        return a;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value != a)
        {
            a = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does `a = a` still trigger the object's `set` method? I don't really want that triggered.

Comment: Oh, sorry, my bad. :)

Answer (score 2):

Having run into this situation myself, I decided to check my code where I deal with this. I tend to have two solutions, both involving the null coalescing operator.

Case 1: Initialization. Using your values from above, this becomes:

```
object a = null ?? something;
```

Obviously, I wouldn't write that line of code (resharper would complain if nothing else). But it is the essence of what is happening. If I have the two (or more) values available when I create `a`, then I write it like this.

Case 2: Never set `a`, but use `??` when `a` is used. In this case, the code would be:

```
MethodTakingA(a ?? b);
```

If there are multiple method calls or other places where I'd need to use `??`, then this is a bad idea.

There is a third case where I do the exact assignment you are avoiding. That is when one of the parameters to my method might be null, and I have a default value to use in that case (as opposed to throwing an `ArgumentNullException`). Here's an example:

```
public void Foo(string str)
{
  str = str ?? String.Empty;
  //Use str as needed below without fear that it might be null.
}
```

I'd like a better answer for this case, but I'm certainly not writing code where micro-optimizing that assignment is worthwhile, and the theoretical answer of

```
string localStr = str ?? String.Empty;
```

Is just adding a new variable to add one. It otherwise serves me no purpose, so I keep my self-assignment and live with it.

Answer (score 2):

I think the new feature that came with C# 8.0, make this pretty easy .There is a new [??= operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator) that chek the variable and if it is null than set the value , if not than nothing.

```
if (variable is null)
{
   variable = expression;
}
```

is simply doing as

```
variable ??= expression;
```

**in your case it is :**

```
a ??= b;
```

Answer (score 1):

As a single statement,

```
var result = ((a == null) ? (a = b) : null);
```

The value of `result` can then be discarded. Having `a` and `b` as object properties, and adding a `Console.WriteLine()` on the setting for `a` will show that it is only assigned to when it was previously null.

The only thing that stops it being perfectly clean is that a throwaway variable `result` is created; hopefully it's still clean enough.

---

Addendum - I've just realised you can also use:

```
var result = a ?? (a = b);
```

as an even shorter version of the above. Again, `a = b` is only evaluated if `a` is `null`.